# Using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to toggle a second element by clicking on the first, and not having the second as interactive but it's not working. What am I doing wrong? The element`.timage` should change itself and the element `. rimage` when selected, but only the element`.timage` should be clickable.

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.target.matches('.timage'))
    this.classList.toggle('change');
}
document.querySelector('.container4').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

```css
.container4 {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline- block;
}

.timage {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
}

.change .timage {
  left: 200px;
}

.rimage {
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
}

.change .rimage {
  position: relative;
  left 500px;
}
```

```html
<a id="mobile-nav" href="#">
  <div class="container4" onclick="myFunction
    (this,event)">
    <div class="container4">
      <div class="timage"><img class="size-medium wp- 
    image-13846" src="http://4309.co.uk/wp-  
    content/uploads/2020/05/
    IMG_20200509_104613- 
    288x300.jpg" alt="" width="70" height="300" />.
      </div>
      <div class="rimage">
        <img class="size-medium wp- 
    image-13669" src="http://4309.co.uk/
    wp-content/uploads
    /2020/05/IMG_20200508_1
    30758-287x300.jpg" alt="" width="90" height="300" />.
      </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably clicking the `img`, not the `div` that the image is in, so `event.target` is the `img`.

To find the nearest ancestor (starting with the current element) that matches a selector, use `closest`.

You're also using `myFunction` both in `onclick="myFunction(this,event)"` and in an `addEventListener` call. Those will provide different arguments to the function. Remove the `onclick` and just use `addEventListener`.

Here's the updated function:

```
function myFunction(x) {
  const timage = x.target.closest(".timage");
  if (timage && this.contains(timage)) {
    this.classList.toggle('change');
  }
}
```

The reason for the `contains` is just completeness and in many cases you can leave it off: It's to defend against `closest` having gone past the container element and found the match in the container's ancestors. That won't happen with your layout because `timage` is only used with the container, but for more general situations, I include that check. For instance:

```
<div class="x">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="x">xxx</div>
        <div class="y">yyy</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There, if I have `click` hooked on `#container` and the user clicks `yyy` and I'm doing `const x = event.target.closest(".x")`, I'll get the `.x` that's the parent of the container. So `this.contains(x)` weeds those out.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks but doesn't seem to work. Nothing toggles at all now. Also, just to be clear, `timage` should toggle and control both

Comment: @Stackinnerflow - I missed that you were passing `this` as the first argument to `myFunction`. (I suggest using `addEventListener` instead.) I've updated it. It should definitely toggle itself. As I note in the answer, you'll have to add code to toggle the other.

Comment: Still doesn't toggle. Am i missing something? Thanks

Comment: @Stackinnerflow - It was toggling, it's just it was toggling on the `timage` element; looking at your CSS (and your original code), you wanted to toggle it on the container. My bad. Also note that you're hooking up your `myFunction` twice, and the way you're doing that won't work. I've updated the answer to address that as well.